# How to remove .php extension using htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I have `.htaccess` file and inside it I have this code:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  Options +FollowSymlinks
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  RewriteRule (.*) /cvsrrc/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I tried to add this which removes the .php extension but, I got 404'd.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```

What I want to achieve is to add some code on my htaccess to remove the .php extension without removing the existing code above because I used that for my angular route. Thanks!

Comment: The "RewriteRule (.*) /cvsrrc/index.php [L]" would be executed before your new added code. Maybe if you'd put the new line above it?

Comment: I already tried that sir, but seems not working.

Comment: To access your files without extensions, just add the following line to your .htaccess : **Options +Multiviews**

Comment: Thanks @starkeen! It works for me

Comment: Your welcome! Glad it helped. cheers.

Comment: Can I contact you in facebook sir? I have some questions regarding on angularjs' `$htttp.get` function. Im having trouble with it. Thanks! @starkeen

Comment: Trish, I am not good at angularJs , if you are having any problem related to this language, please ask a new question with AngularJs tag. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

edit:

```
RewriteEngine On

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L]

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Maybe you need a restart of your apache/httpd server

Comment: The code above should not be change because it has to do with something on my page.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. Got this from my project:

```
#example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]

#301 from example.com/page.html to example.com/page
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]

## don't touch /forum URIs
RewriteRule ^forums/ - [L,NC]

## hide .php extension snippet

# To externally redirect /dir/foo.php to /dir/foo
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R,L]

# To internally forward /dir/foo to /dir/foo.php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: The code above should not be change because it has to do with something on my page.

Comment: this php snippet is working perfect on HTTP, but doesn't rewrite on HTTPS - any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

As @starkeen says, just add the following line into my `.htaccess` code. And here it is :

```
 Options +Multiviews
```

Answer (score 0):

This one works for me

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php
```